# DHCP Stopped working over Bonding

Tags: networking, dhcp, network-bridge, network-bonding

Something recent broke DHCP and Bonding. I used to be able to do this:

```
# This file describes the network interfaces available on your system
# and how to activate them. For more information, see interfaces(5).

# The loopback network interface
auto lo
iface lo inet loopback

auto eth0
iface eth0 inet manual
    bond-master bond0

auto eth1
iface eth1 inet manual
    bond-master bond0

auto bond0
iface bond0 inet manual 
    bond-slaves none
    bond-mode 802.3ad
    bond-miimon 100
    bond-downdelay 200
    bond-updelay 200

auto lan0
iface lan0 inet dhcp
    bridge_ports bond0
    bridge_fd 0
    bridge_maxwait 0
```

Now, the DHCP client is launching but not traffic is exiting the ethernet ports. The crazy thing is, a static address on the bridge *does* work. Any ideas?

Comment: Maybe check dhclient.conf for interface settings - maybe you listen only on the specific interface (i.e. eth0) and you should change it to bond0?

Comment: I found this old thread that might be useful: http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=864657

Comment: This may also be useful: https://wiki.debian.org/Bonding

Comment: Actually, I think the problem is _no_ broadcast traffic is flowing across the bridge. Very strange...

Comment: If I bridge across a normal port, not a bond... this _does_ work. If take out the bridge, and attempt DHCP on a bond, it does _not_ work. So something about DHCP and bonding is busted :(

Comment: Have you checked dhclient.conf for interface settings?

Answer (score 1):

Agh... after much frustration and packet captures... this wasn't an Ubuntu problem. Turns out, somehow DHCP Snooping got enabled on the upstream Cisco switch and we had no trusted interfaces defined.